# Group at two levels with totals in array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Result from pipeline so far:

```
[
  {
    catId: 'A1',
    categories: [
      {
         name: 'Monitors',
         section: 99
      },
      {
         name: 'Monitors',
         section: 99
      },
      {
         name: 'Monitors',
         section: 98
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I've grouped it by cat id and used $push to to fill categories array.

I want also group the categories array

```
[
  {
     catId: 'A1',
     categories: [
       {
          name: 'Monitors',
          section: 99,
          count: 2
       }
       {
         name: 'Monitors',
         section: 98,
         count: 1
       }
     ]
  }
]
```

I havent found any example of how to do a $group on a array.

My query so far:

```
let query = mongoose.model('categories').aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {catId: '$catId'},
            categories: {$push: {name: "$name", section: "$section"}}
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            catId: '$_id.catId',
            categories: 1,
            _id: 0,
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: please add your current query

Comment: There are ways, but if you actually want to do this based on existing aggregation so far then what makes the most sense is to show you existing pipeline and source documents. Because the "most effective" of those ways is to actually consider adding in those totals and the aggregation level in the first place, before you get to this stage of results.

Comment: Updated question with query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So instead of what you are doing, do another [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) first:

```
let query = mongoose.model('categories').aggregate([
    { $group: {
      _id: { catId: "$catId", name: "$name", section: "$section" },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }},
    { $group: {
      _id: '$_id.catId',
      categories: {
        $push: {
          name: "$_id.name",
          section: "$_id.section",
          count: "$count"
        }
      }
    }}
]);
```

Also get used to living with `_id` as the primary key of output, since adding additional [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stages is really just wasting CPU and I/O. The field names are what they are, and the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stages do a good enough job of that.